# yum update error in RHEL 5.11

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

```
http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2 from RHEL_Server: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I am getting this error in RHEL 5.7 version,but this error is not occuring in RHEL 6 .

In RHEL 6.7:-

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id                                                                                        repo name                                                                                       status
NetAct-product-16.2.0.677                                                                      NetAct product 16.2.0.677                                                                       1,051
RHEL_HighAvailability                                                                          "RHEL HighAvailability"                                                                            56
RHEL_LoadBalancer                                                                              "RHEL LoadBalancer"                                                                                 4
RHEL_ScalableFileSystem                                                                        "RHEL ScalableFileSystem"                                                                           7
RHEL_Server                                                                                    "RHEL Server"                                                                                   3,648
RHEL_cpf_Errata                                                                                "RHEL cpf Errata"                                                                               4,255
repolist: 9,021
```

In RHEL 5.11:-

```
yum repolist
RHEL_Server/primary_db                                                                                                                                                        | 3.1 MB     00:00
http://10.91.209.2:81/builds/rhel/RHEL6.4-Server-x86_64/Server/repodata/af55926cd66a289d9c7eaf352b2ed91ca0e28f91a505fff2b5c4c7cc2f1885e0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -3] Error performing checksum
Trying other mirror.
repo id                                                                                        repo name                                                                                       status
NetAct-product-16.2.0.677                                                                      NetAct product 16.2.0.677                                                                       1051
RHEL_Server                                                                                    "RHEL Server"                                                                                      0
RHEL_cpf_Errata                                                                                "RHEL cpf Errata"                                                                                  0
repolist: 1051
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because those are separate repositories and separate metadata.

You can try to clean up all metadata via `yum clean all --enablerepo="*"` and then try again. But if the error with the mirror persists you would need to use a different mirror or contact the mirror owner so he can take a look. Seems the last sync was only partial or not successful.